# Set Window almost Topmost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, topmost

I code an editor, that should have a fullscreen-mode (editor covers 100% of the screen, taskbar is not visible). "Set the Window Topmost" you would say, but here´s the problem: my editor runs external programs, that have to be visible.

My editor should hide the taskbar, but not be topmost for other applications. Is this possible? And how?

Comment: What happens if you set the other windows to always on top as well? You can use Windows API to do that.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make part of a window transparent?

Comment: ofcourse you can, make your toplevel window transparent and then use panels with actual backgrounds for the non-transparent part. I'm not sure how that solves your problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a TopMost window to cover the taskbar.  Creating a borderless maximized window is enough:

```
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
    }
```

You still need a way for the user to activate a window of another application.  It isn't clear what you had in mind, but Alt+Tab works.